# function<void(T)> parameter with default argument

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function with a parameter of type `function<void(int)>`.
I want to have a default argument for `function<void(int)>`.

Here is a sample code :

```
class worker {
public:
    void do_the_job(function<void(int)> call_back = &worker::_log_call_back) {
        // doing the job ...
        call_back(1);
        // doing the job ...
        call_back(-1);
    }

    private:
        void _log_call_back(int status){
            cout << "status: " << status << endl;
        }
};
```

When i compile above code i get the fallowing error:

```
    worker().do_the_job(); // visual studio 2013 error
    //error C2664: 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,int>::_Set(std::_Func_base<_Ret,int> *)' :
    //cannot convert argument 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Ret,int> *'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional
```

why ? and how to fix it ?

Comment: You promise a function, but give it a method. Change the method to a static, or make the default null (with logic to call the method if null), or change the signature to take a method.

Comment: You're using `::std::function` wrongly. Place a lambda into it or use `::std::bind`.

Comment: Judging from `C2664` you're in Visual studio. It compiles fine in VS2013, what version are you using ?

Comment: @user1095108 `std::function` is not restricted to lambdas and calls to `std::bind`. It pretty much acts as a wrapper to a function pointer, so that would be a weird restriction.

Comment: If you are using an earlier version, make _log_call_back a static function.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode It is, more generally, a function object wrapper and he seemingly wanted to call a method, so I made that suggestion.

Comment: @user1095108 yeah, I meant object, not pointer :L but it's too late to edit that now I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&worker::_log_call_back` is the syntax to get a member function pointer, but a member function pointer isn't callable directly, as it holds no information on which instance was used to obtain it (and indeed, no instance was used to obtain it).

Unfortunately, even if you try to work around that, default arguments cannot use `this`, even indirectly. For example,

```
struct S {
  int m;
  void f(int = m) { }
};
```

also fails.

Unless you can make `_log_call_back` into something that doesn't require passing `this`, for example a static member function, the only way to get this working is by not using a default argument. Use an overload instead:

```
void do_the_job(function<void(int)> call_back) {
  ...
}
void do_the_job() {
  do_the_job(std::bind(&worker::_log_call_back, this, std::placeholders::_1)));
}
```

or, if you prefer:

```
void do_the_job() {
  do_the_job([&](int status) { _log_call_back(status); });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`_log_call_back` has a `worker *` as a hidden parameter while `function<void(int)>` does not, so they are not compatible. You can use `static void _log_callback` to remove the hidden parameter.
Alternatively you can use [pointer to member function](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c17401/C-Tutorial-PointertoMember-Function.htm) such as `void (worker::*p)(int) = worker::_log_call_back`.